Decrypt s63 IHO
I'm developing an OEM System for s63 charts.
I didn't find lot of information about the s63 decryption, however I read the IHO Data Protection Scheme, but I don't understand everything.
With Python, I use the algorithm AES MODE_ECB but I'm not sure if that's the right one.
When I run my program, the compressed s57 is create but I've an error when I dezip it. (I test my program with testDatas_IHO, so the key and the chart are correct).
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

input_fileENC = './NO4D0512.000' #s63
output_fileENC = './s57/NO4D0512.zip' #s57

key1 = b'9C467D359D000000'
key2 = b'27737811B4000000'

print("----Decrypt----")

# Open s63
with open(input_fileENC, 'rb') as s63_file_en:
    # Read whole file
    s63_data = s63_file_en.read()

decipher = AES.new(key1, AES.MODE_ECB)

msg_dec = decipher.decrypt(s63_data)
print("s57: ",msg_dec)

# Create s57_dec
with open(output_fileENC, 'wb') as s57_file_dec: 
    s57_file_dec.write(msg_dec)

